# How can I iterate over a vector of base class objects?

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl

I have an problem where we need to have a number of shapes, such as a Circle and Square which can be position on a flat, 2 dimensional plane. All shapes, such as Circle and Square inherit from an abstact base class Shape; as such I have a vector of pointers to shapes.

However, I need to be able to iterate over the plane and find any shapes which collide, such that they are intersecting or touching. If I get a shape from the vector, I don't know if it is a Square or a Circle because it has been sliced to the Shape base class.

How would I be best solving this problem?

```
#ifndef Plane_h
#define Plane_h

#include <vector>
#include "Shape.h"

class Plane {
public:
    Plane(std::vector<Shape*>);
    Plane(const Plane&);
    ~Plane();

    void add(Shape*);
    std::vector<Shape*> all() const;

protected:
    std::vector<Shape*> shapes;
};

#endif
```

Comment: There's no reason in that code for the shapes to have been sliced. Could you show the code where you add the shapes to the vector.

Comment: I suppose it could be that you don't understand what 'sliced' means. Could you show the code where you acutally think you have the problem?

Comment: Common case of object obsession. This is not necessarily a meaningful inheritance tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use polymorphism. Add a virtual method on your Shape class:

```
class Shape {
  ...
  virtual bool intersects(Shape const* otherShape);
  ...
}
```

Then you implement it for each different shape. Then if it's used like:

```
Shape* A = getShapeA();
Shape* B = getShapeB();
if (A->intersects(B))
  doSomething();
```

The correct version is called, i.e if `A` is a `Circle`, `Circle::intersects` is called. But in there, you still don't know what shape `B` actually is. You can find this out by trying to do a dynamic cast:

```
Circle* circle = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(otherShape);
if (circle)
  intersectsCircle(circle);
```

Comment: So you suggest trying a `dynamic_cast` for each shape until one works? That is far from optimal.

Comment: Very valid warning, dynamic casting is not really efficient. Having an enumeration of object type, as suggested by user1158692, may be more efficient, but always strikes me as ugly. In practice I would probably use something like a visitor pattern, but judging the learning stage of OP, polymorphism + dynamic cast should maybe be the first thing to learn about/try.

Comment: Just another voice saying "do **not** do it like this", as the answer seems to advocate repeatedly dynamic casting until something sticks.

Comment: Seeing as I agree, I wrote another answer that shows a better practice.

Answer (score 2):

Your classes have not been sliced.  **This** would result in a sliced object:

```
vector<Shape> vec;
Circle circ;
vec.push_back(circ);
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing

In your instance the instantiated objects remain whole and the pointers point to whole objects - but it is almost certainly true that in order to calculate intersections you will need to do some downcasting.  While this is to be done as little as possible it's not a crime in itself.

Your best bet would be to provide a method in the base class to return a value indicating the object type - maybe use an enumeration - and use that to downcast a particular `Shape` pointer or reference to a pointer/reference to the correct derived type.

An abstract method in the base `Shape` class like `bool Intersects( const Shape& obj )` could be overridden by the derived classes, the overrides downcasting the parameter to the correct derived type.

Alternatively you might prefer to provide a global/static method taking two shapes, or privately implement that method and call it from the instance method `Intersects()`

( Detecting the intersections is not exactly a trivial task.  :-) )

Comment: How would I know if that Shape& is a Circle or a Square? Obviously, the method of computing if two intersect is different for a Circle and Circle, Circle and Square and Square and Square.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson from the answer: *"Your best bet would be to provide a method in the base class to return a value indicating the object type - maybe use an enumeration - and use that to downcast a particular Shape pointer or reference to a pointer/reference to the correct derived type."*

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method, that does not need dynamic casts (or any explicit cast at all), or an ugly enum listing the subclasses. It is based on [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch), which basically works by going through two virtual methods in order to determine the types of the two objects you want to work on.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Circle;
class Square;

struct Shape
{
  virtual void intersect(Shape* otherShape) = 0;
  virtual void intersect(Circle* otherCircle) = 0;
  virtual void intersect(Square* otherSquare) = 0;
};

struct Circle : public Shape
{
  virtual void intersect(Shape* otherShape)
  {
    otherShape->intersect(this);
  }

  virtual void intersect(Circle* otherCircle)
  {
    cout << "Intersecting Circle with Circle" << endl;
  }

  virtual void intersect(Square* otherSquare)
  {
    cout << "Intersecting Circle with Square" << endl;
  }
};

struct Square : public Shape
{
  virtual void intersect(Shape* otherShape)
  {
    otherShape->intersect(this);
  }

  virtual void intersect(Circle* otherCircle)
  {
    otherCircle->intersect(this);
  }

  virtual void intersect(Square* otherSquare)
  {
    cout << "Intersecting Square with Square" << endl;
  }

};

int main()
{
  Circle circle;
  Square square;

  circle.intersect(&square);

  Shape* shapeA = &circle;
  Shape* shapeB = &square;

  shapeA->intersect(shapeA);
  shapeA->intersect(shapeB);
  shapeB->intersect(shapeA);
  shapeB->intersect(shapeB);
}
```

Note that here you still have to list all possible subclasses within the base class, but in this case in the form of overloads of the `intersect` for each base class. If you fail to add all (say, you make a `class Triangle : public Shape`, but no `Shape::intersect(Triangle*)`), you end up with infinite call loops.

Also note that in this example I did a 'triple' dispatch, so I don't have to implement the logic to intersect a `Circle` with a `Square` twice.

Comment: A shame they accepted your first answer and will probably never see this.  +1 all the same.